# Angular2 Error - Property 'innerWidth' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: typescript, angular

In my Angular2 app I get the following error:

```
 app/src/main.ts(104,42): error TS2339: Property 'innerWidth' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

I have the following method in my component and the compiler doesn't like the `innerWidth` property of my event object.

```
onWindowResize(event: Event):void {
        if (event.target && event.target.innerWidth >= 768) {
            this.showMenu = false;
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do to prevent / overcome this error? I thought that the first check of `if (event.target` would prevent such a crash. Also the error only occurred when I gave the event argument the type definition of `Event`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems using `event.target[innerWidth]` doesn't produce such an error but my code no longer works?

Comment: In my case, event.target['innerWidth'] works (note the quotes around innerWidth)

Comment: Have you tried the solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066698/402339

Answer (score 3):

You can override Event class like this:

```
interface MyEventTarget extends EventTarget {
    innerWidth: number
}

interface MyEvent extends Event {
    target: MyEventTarget;
}
```

Then your code is changed to:

```
onWindowResize(event: MyEvent):void { <== new created class
  if (event.target && event.target.innerWidth >= 768) {
     this.showMenu = false;
  }
}
```