# How can I display an image using Typescript and Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am very new to typescript and web development in general so I am sorry if my code is terrible. Anyways, I am having an issue displaying a "preview image" for a profile picture upload. I am using ng2-file-upload to upload my image to the server and that part is working correctly. Before I click the upload button I want to display the selected image on the page right after it has been selected. Currently I am trying to display the image by retrieving the src property from the HTMLImageElement but the src property appears to be empty.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'http://localhost:4200/api/upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-profile',
  templateUrl: './view-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-profile.component.css']
})
export class ViewProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL, itemAlias: 'newProfilePicture'});
  title: string;
  previewImage: any;
  tempImage: any;
  source: string;

  imagePreview(input) 
  {
      document.getElementById("previewImage").style.display="block";
      
        console.log("Image is selected")
        this.previewImage = document.getElementById("previewImage");
        console.log(this.previewImage);
        
        this.source = (<HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById('previewImage')).src
        console.log("Image Source: " + this.source + " Should be inbetween here");
        
      
      //var reader = new FileReader();
        
        //console.log(this.previewImage);
      
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.title = 'View or Update Your Profile';
   this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file)=> {file.withCredentials = false;};
   this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item:any, response:any, status:any, headers:any) => {
        console.log("ImageUpload:uploaded:", item, status, response);
    //this.imagePreview();


    };
  }


}
```

And here is my HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>

    <div>

        <input type="file" id="previewImage" (change)="imagePreview(this);" name="newProfilePicture" ng2FileSelect [uploader] ="uploader" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s" (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
          Upload Your File
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Not really. He did ask how to do it in Typescript and Angular4 specifically.

Answer (score 37):

You achive this by this simple function :

Template :

```
<img [src]="url" height="200"> <br/>
<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
```

Component :

```
onSelectFile(event) { // called each time file input changes
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the working example of it, please check this out:

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview)**

Comment: @Kenny Ho, will you please accpet and upvote the answer?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I got `error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on ty
pe 'EventTarget'.` which is this line inside of onSelectFile(event) `this.url = event.target.result;` If I change it to anything, ng cli will auto-recompile successfully. Repeat will create get the error back.  Any thought?

Comment: Jeb50 Add `<File>` cast to `event.target.files` and `event.target.files[0]`

Comment: I have used this code but for me it is working but with two problems

at reader.onload = (event) [tslint] Shadowed name: 'event' (no-shadowed-variable

and to the
this.person.photo = event.target.result
// Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Comment: Regarding the TS error, instead of using event.target.result, you can just use reader.result

Comment: You sample is working well. However, I have some question on how to implement such opening mechaning when the area to display uploaded image was in different set from the button set: display section is in sketch.component.html / sketch.component.ts / sketch.component.spec / sketch.component.scss  set while the buttons set is in topnav.component.html / topnav.component.ts / topnav.component.spec / topnav.component.scss  set while the input [<input>] must be hidden. If you can come up with example like this one, I will be appreciate.

Answer (score 8):

Template :

```
<input type='file' (change)="readUrl($event)">
<img [src]="url">
```

Component :

```
 readUrl(event:any) {
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = (event:any) => {
              this.url = event.target.result;
          }

          reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      }
 }
```

T tried it, and it works without any error.

Comment: I have used this code but it is showing me one error

reader.onload = (event:any) // event Shadowed name: 'event' (no-shadowed-variable)