# Property innerWidth does not exist on type EventTarget

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting

When I run a code:

```
public onResize(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.target.innerWidth);

    //--solution--
    //var w = event.target as Window;
    //console.log(w.innerWidth);
  }
```

I receive an error:

```
Property innerWidth does not exist on type EventTarget
```

I would like to avoid extending types in TypeScript (as it is described here [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget) ), so I cast `event.target` to `Window` class. I'm not sure if I cast to proper class. Which class should I cast to? How to find out a proper class which should be cast to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what element you registered the event listener on, then you could cast `event.target` to that element type.  I don't think there's any more to say than that.  Alternatively, you can directly reference the element you registered the listener on (in this case just the global `window`) rather than using `event.target`.

Comment: I know an element I registered the event listener on, but I don't know a type of the element. For example let's assume it is `<canvas>` : if I register event listener on a canvas, how to find out the type of that element? Is it `Canvas` or `HTMLCanvasElement`, or maybe none of them? Is anywhere any documentation which describes JavaScript classes? I have been looking for it on ( https://developer.mozilla.org ) but I couldn't find.

Comment: For <canvas>, if you look at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas), the "DOM interface" is `HTMLCanvasElement`, and that should generally be the name to use in TypeScript too.

Answer (score 26):

1. A resize event uses the **UIEvent** Interface.

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event
2. A UIEvent has a target property which, unfortunately, has no "innerWidth" property. So, instead, we assert the **target** of the event ***as Window***

i.e.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (event: UIEvent) => {
  const w = event.target as Window; 
  console.log(w.innerWidth) // works!
});
```