# how do i type e.key and e.target.value with typescript in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i need e.key and e.target.value but i can't seem to make it work with this code:

```
const handleInputKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement> ) => {
  if(e.key ==='Enter') { 
    dfTextQuery(e.target.value)
  }
};
```

why is target not having the value property? and i am getting an error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

i was expecting with HTMLInputElement, it should work. how do i type e.key and e.target.value with typescript in react?

Comment: are you tried (e.target as  HTMLInputElement).value`?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan it worked! didn't know that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

Comment: glad to help. it is the assertion in typescript. more about it https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 4):

In the browser, events are bubbling, going from child to parent.
the `target` element from your event is the source of the original event.
In your case, the keyboard event will be dispatched from your input field, and will never come from another child.

Instead of using `target`, you can use `currentTarget` which corresponds to the DOM element on which the listener is attached. This will be your input field, and so will always be an HTMLInputElement.