# Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. [deprecated]

Tags: angular, scroll

I try to use scrollTop to detected where the user scroll on some div but got this error.

I try to implement this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqvraz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsticky-header.directive.ts

I am looking for a replacement for this option.
Thanks.

Comment: Its not an error, just a warning from typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ?

```
 console.log($event.srcElement['scrollLeft'], $event.srcElement['scrollTop']);
```