# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ngtsc(2339)

Tags: angular, typescript, events, properties, emit

I am using Angular 11.1.4 and typscript 4.1.5.
I get this error at many points...

http://i.hizliresim.com/3ngawR.png
https://i.hizliresim.com/3ngawR.png
How can I fix mistakes in the picture.

Same Title Available!;

The solutions given do not work because they have the same title but have different angular versions.

Comment: What happens when you try to compile/build/run the project?

Comment: it happens like this.;
https://i.hizliresim.com/rpdX39.png

Comment: Try using `currentTarget` instead of `target`.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/MHKzqv.png
It didn't happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: You **MUST** update the question to contain the relevant code as (formatted) plain text. Picture links = link rot, too much overhead, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image link doesn't work. Anyway you can try this.

`const { value, classList, ... } = $event.target as HTMLButtonElement;`

Change HTMLButtonElement interface with the interface of the element you are trying to get the event from.

for exemple : `HTMLDivElement` or `HTMLInputElement`