# Angular 12. error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, select, angular-directive

I am following the pro angular 6 3rd edition book tutorial and I am finding it hard to resolve the issue with value of a $event.target. it is suppose to be an option to limit the number of articles per page on display. but I cannot get it to work, my main issue now I think is that the feature is no longer available in angular 12.

ts code is as follows:

...

```
changePage(newPage: number){
    this.selectedPage = newPage;
}

changePageSize(newSize: number){
    this.productsPerPage = Number(newSize);
    this.changePage(1);
}

get pageNumbers(): number[]{
    return Array(Math.ceil(this.repository.getProducts(this.selectedCategory)
      .length / this.productsPerPage)).fill(0).map((x, i)=> i +1);
 }
```

...

```
enter code here
```

html template part with the issue
...

```
 <select class="form-control" [value]="productsPerPage"
    (change)="changePageSize($event.target.value)">
        <option value="3">3 per Page</option>
        <option value="4">4 per Page</option>
        <option value="6">6 per Page</option>
        <option value="8">8 per Page</option>
    </select>
```

...
I appreciate any solutions that may help.

Comment: That should be a type casting error because typescript believes that changePageSize is using HtmlElement as a type. Here is a good article about it: https://freshman.tech/snippets/typescript/fix-value-not-exist-eventtarget/ or you can look at the angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/event-binding-concepts. In your case you probably should use HTMLSelectElement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066421/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget)

Comment: those are good reads that has helped me understand angular and typescript better. Thank you user3658510.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't just put:

HTML:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="productsPerPage">
        <option value="3">3 per Page</option>
        <option value="4">4 per Page</option>
        <option value="6">6 per Page</option>
        <option value="8">8 per Page</option>
    </select>
```

NOTE: You have to import NgModule in your module.

For instance, in your app.module.ts:

```
...
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...


imports: [
...
    FormsModule,
...
]
```

Comment: Hi Juan, you are a super hero, I am not sure why I did not think of that but thank you very much it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

bro just put $any before $event.target
just like that `($any($event.target).value)`

full code

```
 <select class="form-control" [value]="productsPerPage"
        (change)="changePageSize($any($event.target).value)">
            <option value="3">3 per Page</option>
            <option value="4">4 per Page</option>
            <option value="6">6 per Page</option>
            <option value="8">8 per Page</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck)

> When using $event.target for DOM events (because of the possibility of
> event bubbling, $event.target in the DOM typings doesn't have the type
> you might expect) in that case we can use $any() type-cast function opt out of type-checking for a part of the expression

```
<select class="form-control" [value]="productsPerPage"
    (change)="changePageSize($any($event.target.value))">
        <option value="3">3 per Page</option>
        <option value="4">4 per Page</option>
        <option value="6">6 per Page</option>
        <option value="8">8 per Page</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: although I did get the solution from Juan's solution below, I still tried your solution but it did not solve my problem I am afraid. Many thanks though :)

Answer (score -1):

inside (change), you should pass $event only. Inside logic, you should take event.target.value

Comment: Nikhil, I had tried this before posting this question and it had not worked. the changes recommended by Juan below was what worked.