# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339) - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm trying to use `onChange` function on a slider, but I keep getting and error with the Value. Am I doing something wrong ?

I'm using TypeScript and ViteJS.

[image: Value error]

My code:

```html
      <Slider
        color="success"
        aria-label="Small steps"
        defaultValue={0.00000005}
        step={1}
        marks
        min={5}
        max={20}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        value={passwordLength}
        onChange={(e) => setPasswordLength(e.target.value)}
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error reported:
[Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Qlt.png)

Since you are using a custom component `<Slider>`, you need to explicitly tell TypeScript the type of the `HTMLElement` which is your target.

[Look at this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42066698/7033357)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `e.target`, instead use `e.currentTarget`.

In JavaScript `e.target` refers to the element on which the event was fired, which may be the current element or it may be it's child. Usually for inputs you never have onChange events for children, but TypeScript doesn't know that, so it complains.

If you instead use `e.currentTarget` then TypeScript will know that the target is not a child element of the Slider input, so it will allow you to use `e.currentTarget.value`.

Comment: just switches to `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & Element'` unfortunately :/

Comment: @NickW You must be doing something wrong. Check your code. I can't help you much without seeing what you have tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add $any to resolve the issue:

```
setPasswordLength($any(e.target).value)}
```

Comment: Casting to `any` is never a good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

in TypeScript and Angular

```
(input)="dt.filter(getTarget($event.target).value, // other code
```

and

```
getTarget(target: EventTarget | null): HTMLInputElement {
    return target as HTMLInputElement;
  }
```